# How to execute Multiquery in PHP - dynamic code php

Tags: php, mysql

I've this multiquery

```
enter code here

SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT

      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(case when b.periode = ''',
          date_format(periode, '%Y-%m-%d'),
          ''' then b.item_terjual end) AS `',
           date_format(periode, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`' 
        ) ORDER BY periode SEPARATOR ',\n' 
      ) INTO @sql
    from penjualan; 


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT a.kd_barang,', @sql,'

     FROM t_barang a
     INNER JOIN penjualan b ON a.kd_barang = b.kd_barang
     GROUP BY a.kd_barang
     ORDER BY a.kd_barang');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

how to excute in PHP , to display table like this

kd_barang | 2014-08-15 | 2014-09-15 | xxx.... 
123            | 100                    | 200
124            | 200                   | 300

I try this  code but its not dynamic

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$q))
{
  do
    {

    // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con))
      {

      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

                printf("%s\n",$row[1]);

                                echo "<br>";
        $count++;
        }
      mysqli_free_result($con);
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
print_r($data);


mysqli_close($con);
```

How do I execute multiple queries dynamically in PHP?

Comment: MAX is a function. dont use single quote in front

Comment: kd_barang = kode barang ? :D

Comment: fortune : my sql was working .. but i dont know how to execute in php code :(

Comment: nucleo : iyaa .. pernah eksekusi multiquery ke php gak ?

Comment: Sering, ada ym ? biar lbh cpt?

Comment: Btw, krg enak di baca yg laen. Ini buat pulling data kan? bukan insert data mksd nya ?

Comment: yah .. udah lama gak pake ym .. download dulu deh . ym nya apa ? nanti gue yang add .. makasih :)

Comment: Google chat boleh, ignorantforgotten@gmail.com emailnya, tar ksh tau skema sql nya scra keseluruhan.

Comment: okee .. thanks ya .. gue add nih otw

Comment: @tara google chat? oke. baru cek ym udah ga ada jg :D

Comment: Its better to write a store procedure and call the procedure from your php file using mysqli

Comment: @jewelhuq do yo have example to write stored procedure ? i never use it ..

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843 try this to learn about store procedure.